# Grunt-contrib-sass compile single file and directory

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to work out how to compile a single file as well as a directory and for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

```
sass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      style: 'expanded'
    },
    files: [
    {'style.css': 'style.scss'},
    {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '/scss/',
      src: '*.scss',
      dest: '/css',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

This only seems to compile the style.css and ignores the directory.

Because of WordPress' weird requirements, having the style.css file separate (one level up) from the CSS directory is quite common. An example would also be useful for compiling multiple directories too.

Comment: Have you tried the `**/'.sass` pattern? http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assumed that to work too. It might be a bug in grunt. Feel free to [open a ticket](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/new).

You can use multiple targets to work around it in the meantime:

```
sass: {
  options: {
    style: 'expanded'
  },
  dev: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '/scss/',
      src: '*.scss',
      dest: '/css',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  },
  dev2: {
    files: [{'style.css': 'style.scss'}]
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks! I also managed to get the original method to work which would suggest it was user error :)

Comment: Dude, if you made it work, please share your solution the next time. I could have used some advice here now.

Comment: @lawlesscreation agree with sra, how did you get the original to work?